# Gmod - Lua error- 'Attempting to index field 'GM' (a nil value)

Tags: audio, lua

Okay, I just learnt about Lua a few days ago, and I tried to make a very basic script, which of course, doesn't work.

```
function GM:OnNPCKilled( victim, killer, weapon )
local noise = Sound("sadviolin.wav")    
end
```

I get the error:

> Attempting to index field 'GM' (a nil value)

All I want to do is play a sound when an NPC gets killed.

Comment: Why everyone is calling that poor language "LUA" in all-caps? On Wikipedia, it's even mentioned that the name of the language is "Lua (/ˈluːə/ loo-ə, from Portuguese: lua [ˈlu.(w)ɐ] meaning moon; **explicitly not "LUA"[1])**" (emphasis mine)

Comment: It means `GM` doesn't exist in that code context.

Comment: @Greatwolf Yeah, I know that. I don't know how I should change it.

Comment: @Greatwolf Okay, I removed GM:, but now the noise doesn't play at all.

Comment: I think I'm playing the sound wrong.

Comment: Can you `print('hello')` instead of playing a sound? If there is console output then you at least can tell if your function is being called.

Comment: Yeah, printing 'hello' doesn't work. I'm not sure what I should put for the first line. OnNPCKilled is meant to be a function?

Answer (score 1):

You only use "GM:OnNPCKilled" when you are creating a gamemode from scratch
Use this instead:

> function FOnNPCKilled( victim, killer, weapon )
>
> local noise = Sound("sadviolin.wav")
> end
> hook.Add("OnNPCKilled", "UniqueIdentifier1", FOnNPCKilled)

Btw, i fixed your function and I understand what you are trying to do, but that code it's not going to play a sound on players death, you only created a var with the sound on value.

To do that use this instead:

> function FOnNPCKilled( victim, killer, weapon )
>
> surface.PlaySound( "sadviolin.wav", victim:GetPos() )
>
> end
>
> hook.Add("OnNPCKilled", "UniqueIdentifier1", FOnNPCKilled)